# cannot navigate to some profiles on github

Tags: github

In some available repositories I saw contributed users' profiles which I cannot visit - they are basically unavailable -> it's not even marked as link.

When I click on user profile - I can navigate to it. But when I click on this user another - it does nothing.

Do these users set some block or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible those users have made contributions (pushed commits) done with a name+emai which doesn't match any GitHub account.
This is detailed in "[Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/)".

In that case, their username would be displayed, but without any link to a GitHub account.

---

[dennisschagt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1928529/dennisschagt) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881218/cannot-navigate-to-some-profiles-on-github/26882159#comment42331383_26882159):

> [I did some testing some time ago](https://github.com/dennisschagt/st_testing/commits/master) and **GitHub uses the `user.email` field to link commits to users**.
>   If there is no user with that email address, GitHub displays the value of `user.name` but then the name is not clickable.

Comment: but how to visit their accounts?

Comment: @user1432980 that is my point: their username and email do *not* match any GitHub account, which means: you cannot visit their account (since it doesn't exist on GitHub)

Comment: erm...But they contribute to github projects. Because we are in the same team.

Comment: @user1432980 ok, but they didn't use the right username or the right email.

Comment: I see. Well I was able to visit their accounts by @username -> it's found public repositories and I was able to visit their accounts through this.

Comment: @user1432980 I understand, but double-check the name/email used for the commits from which you *cannot* visit their profile: is it the exact name/email as the account you are currently visiting?

Comment: yes. It's the same name as under profile picture under real name and surname

Comment: @user1432980 then I would suspect the email address doesn't match

Comment: I see. Thanks. Because I thought at first that there is an option to restrict access to your profile.

Comment: @user1432980 not to my knowledge: I only know about *public* GitHub accounts, not private ones.

Comment: [I did some testing some time ago](https://github.com/dennisschagt/st_testing/commits/master) and GitHub uses the `user.email` field to link commits to users. If there is no user with that email address, GitHub displays the value of `user.name` but then the name is not clickable.

Comment: @dennisschagt good test! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.